# How to make a Stanford torus start rotating?

Tags: space, space-colonization, space-constructs

The notion of using the so called [Stanford torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_torus) to generate artificial gravity is well known, but once you build the mega-structure how do you make it *start* rotating? Do you rotate somehow from the center, or do you install booster rockets on the circumference?

Also, given the structure is in space, is the energy required for rotation a one time expenditure? Or will friction come in to play and multiple periodic boosts would be required?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cALmXMoyLtQ

Comment: An issue of note adjacent to spinning up the structure is distribution of mass around the torus, and balancing it out during operation.  Ie just a person traveling from one spoke to another will change the weight distribution and contribute to a wobbly wheel. No to mention heavy equipment etc.  One method of control suggested is pumping water / liquid to correspondent areas of the station to offset any mass imbalance, computer automated ofcourse.

Answer (score 14):

Considering that to make something rotate you need to apply a torque, and that the torque momentum is given by the applied force times the distance from the rotation center, it makes more sense to apply pairs of booster rockets on the outer circumference of the torus.

Think of spinning up a bicycle wheel: is it easier to do so grabbing it from the tire or from the axle?

Over time internal losses will slow down the rotation of the torus, and you will use those rockets to boost it up again. But my gut feeling tells me it's not something you will doing very often.

Comment: Internal losses contributing to slowdown would constitute a violation of the conservation of angular momentum. Unless an *external* torque is applied, it'll spin forever. There are sources of external torque (tides, light pressure, friction with interplanetary medium), but they are pretty small and do not uniformly reduced rotation speed.

Comment: Internal(ish) losses could include Coriolis induced wind, causing friction, causing kinetic energy to bleed into space as heat.

Comment: @sdfgeoff Doesn't matter. If you can't dump angular momentum, you can't stop spinning. Angular momentum and energy are conserved separately.

Comment: I think we’re all forgetting that materials to make a construct of this scale rigid enough to survive acceleration don’t exist in hard science, and are difficult to imagine without invoking magic. The specs for this station include radiation shielding which brings the mass up to 10^6 short tons. Frame your question with this in mind: Each of the six spokes is a hollow tube 5 times taller than the Eiffel tower, and holding several hundred thousands of tons in suspension. Do NOT try to torque them!!

Comment: @VogonPoet In a Stanford Torus, which is a very specific design, not just a generic term for toroidal rotating space stations, the radiation shield *does not rotate*, and its mass does not need to be suspended under gravity and does not contribute any hoop stress on the habitation ring or tension on the spokes.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley ah, great find! Then the station itself can use the massive shield as the reaction mass to get it up to speed, since 95% of the mass is shielding. Therefore, the OP answer is quite simple (and already mentioned per your answer. I ran with the OP data too quickly.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Does that mean the artists' interpretations where you can see space through transparent windows are a lie?

Comment: @Nacht No. The radiation shield only extends under the floor and around the walls of the habitation structure--it does not cover the roof, and could not cover the roof because rotating spokes have to occupy that space. That's where the transparent windows are.

Comment: I've been thinking more about it and I think @LoganR.Kearsley is right. In absence of thermal input to the system, wind will reduce in velocity until it's at equilibrium, (putting a wind turbine in the station would not be a source of infinite energy), so the angular momentum is conserved properly with respect to the external universe, and the station will not slow down.

Answer (score 13):

The construction of a rotating space habitat isn't particularly well defined, but acceleration would be required. Here are a few considerations.

#### Superstructure

Initial construction would be performed as a zero-G operation, simply because it would be easier to place objects and bolt/weld them together when they aren't trying to fly away. Once the superstructure was in place, it would be accelerated to low G because, if you have a floor, a tiny amount of gravity keeps things in place.

Plus there's the reality that you'd want to test all of the connections before you attach billions of dollars worth of equipment to it. Initial spin-up would be a major milestone in the construction.

#### Pressurization and full spin-up

There's no point to higher G's before you have an atmosphere, so you'd want to spin it up to final rotational speed some time after pressurization. On the other hand, everything you load aboard will add to the energetic cost of spin-up, so you'd want to do it before you start filling it with objects that might shift around.

A cautious engineering group would spin it up gradually so they could monitor the joints under increasing load, and correct any problems as they crop up.

#### Alternatives for adding spin

There are numerous methods for spinning up a two-kilometer wide disk, depending on how quickly you need to do it. You have to consider that the whole thing wouldn't be rigid. Think of the station like a big, spinning Golden Gate Bridge. You couldn't drive spin from the hub because it would twist and pull on the supports and create a resonant bouncing. This configuration makes flywheel compensation more problematic. If you just hooked up a single ship to one side and turned on the thrusters, it would twist, compress, and yank on the primary hull.

Attitude jets would be necessary to adjust for mass shifts, so that's the simplest solution, but also the least energy efficient. It would be more likely that someone would think to use the construction ships like tug boats.

A construction of that scope would need a continual influx of materials, so you could engineer a mechanism where each incoming shipment were caught to add a little bit of momentum to the spin. The alternative would be to slow the shipment's speed down to nothing, importing it at the hub, then re-accelerating it when you move it to one of the rings. That process would require continual addition of acceleration every time you moved a wall segment in, just to keep it at the same speed.

You could use solar sails to adjust speed over time. I'm imagining they might set them up like an insanely huge pinwheel. You could slingshot mass past it while shipping materials around the solar system, or radiate waste heat from industrial processes in the right direction. You could install launchers to fire finished goods or waste materials from the station, using those as reaction mass.

#### Maintenance

Chances are, they would do all of those things and balance them out with an accounting system. There is some question about how much small adjustments would matter. The base Stanford Torus design calls for about ten *million* tons of mass, so something like moving a cargo container from the hub to the rim would be unnoticeable to humans.

If you had scientific or manufacturing processes that you didn't want to jostle, you'd probably want to set up a train that constantly circled the torus. You could load and offload with segments that matched speeds, and use the train's speed to counteract the small adjustments in the station's rotational moment.

#### Friction?

There is no meaningful friction to spinning in place in outer space. Even in a nebula, it would take millennia before you could measure a difference.

Comment: I like the idea of a two phase construction. Makes total sense. I would even go as far as to over spin the frame, to stress test it. It is easy to slow down by bringing bulk material from the hub to the rim. Also space stations like this would setup a protocol to follow for larger ships to get specific docking instructions from the "control tower" to correct the momentum and orbit of the station with every action. Large ships would influence the station anyway, so why not use it.

Comment: @MennovanLavieren, Yea, that does make sense. I'm imagining that smaller ships might be grabbed and pulled inside, while freighters would launch their containers at a catcher, with computers controlling those behaviors to avoid collisions. I'm also imagining using the freighter's container-launcher being hijacked by terrorists to throw containers at the torus.

Comment: The Stanford torus itself is well defined, it is a massive ship with 10 million short tons mass and 1.8 km radius. The force required to spin it up to the 1rpm from a stop over the span of one year continuous thrust would be F ≈ 1.13 × 10^12 N if it were a simple flywheel. But most of its mass is at the perimeter, so much more is needed. Never mind the astronomical rockets needed to do this “major milestone,” as you correctly call it, but the structure would disintegrate long before it got any speed. Build it already spinning, accelerating each piece at assembly. It is not easier working in 0G

Comment: @VogonPoet, without going into too much physics, how do you propose to hold a girder in place while you connect it while the station is spinning?

Comment: @RobertRapplean Spinning is a relative term. From the point of reference at the worksite, everything feels a consistant downward force that approaches 1G at the very perimeter. I don’t know what girders you refer to, but for segments of the outer ring, they begin at the hub suspended between two of the 6 spokes, lowered as they grow, then attached to the spoke ends. All 6 arches are built simultaneously, and lowered simultaneously. You can’t rush this. But, spinning a final torus would take the same amount of time. Existing tech would take years to spin the final thing up.

Comment: @VogonPoet, Your plan is to slow the unattached chunks down to relative zero, import them at the hub, lower them simultaneously (slowing the torus a little as you lower it, because physics), then re-accelerate the torus to its former rotational speed after it's been attached. That last bit is important because it's indistinguishable from my plan to spin the superstructure after it's been assembled. Same thrusters in the same places providing the same torque. Your plan would start the thrusters earlier than mine, but mine avoids the coordinated lowering.

Comment: @RobertRapplean No that’s not the plan. The structure never lends momentum to the components, they are individually brought to speed with small portable vehicles or simple detachable thrusters. The net acceleration is delivered incrementally through hundreds or maybe thousands of assemblies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147783/discussion-between-robert-rapplean-and-vogon-poet).

Answer (score 8):

**Possible alternative solutions.**

- Have more than one torus:

The central hub would be used for docking as in other solutions, but at each end would be a hub with spokes radiating to a torus, giving you two habitats with gravity and the "axel" for zero g activities.

The hubs can be spun-up by applying torque clockwise to one and counter clockwise to the other using electric motors, to prevent the nasty effect if one torus has more mass than the other making the axel spin, that can be balanced out by raising and lowering weights inside the spokes to trim the angular momentum. Spinup
thrusters would not be needed.

- Triangular pyramid.

Another alternative would be to have a longer axel in tetrahedral formation, allowing for four habitats, and allowing for easy reorientation of the station through differential slowing/speeding-up of the rotation of the tori - transferring some of the rotational momentum to the axels as desired. This would require initial "clamping" of the axel with station keeping thrusters to prevent tumbling during spin up.

Comment: The multi-torus approach has the further benefit of supporting an indefinite number of spin-up/-down cycles without requiring propellant.

Answer (score 4):

The station *should* simply continue rotation if nothing disturbs it. Disturbances might come from spacecraft docking with the station or from the unbalanced movement of masses inside. Momentum would be preserved, so there could be effects like a [figure skater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#General_considerations).

Because of that, I would expect rocket engines on the outer rim. There may also be gyroscopes, to compensate for small changes without expending reaction mass.

Answer (score 4):

### Gyroscopes

Initial spin-up might be assisted by rockets, but fine adjustments would likely be accomplished with gyroscopes on the central axel that spin in the opposite direction. Unless they were truly enormous it would take a LONG time to bring the station from stand still to full rotation, but spinning the gyros would cause the station to rotate in the other direction. The change would be fairly small, but since friction would be minimal, most changes to velocity would be from movement within the structure and ships docking and loading/unloading material and once spinning at final velocity minor corrections in either direction could be accomplished with fairly small (comparative to the structure itself, they'd likely be car sized or larger) gyroscopes.

Comment: Unless the gyros were of the same scale as the station, they would need to spin to enormous velocities which may exceed the tensile strength of known materials.

Comment: Gyroscopes don't actually need to be at the station axis. A gyroscope anywhere on the structure will contribute to its rotation.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan They would need to be big (compared to say a toy gyroscope) but they could be considerably smaller than the station if you're constantly compensating for small changes in spin. It depends on just how much loss/gain of rotation the station regularly is subject to.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are asking *specifically* about a Stanford Torus, not just any old toroidal rotating space station, why not just look at what NASA SP-413 "Space Settlements: A Design Study" (i.e., the document which describes the Stanford Torus design and construction plans) has to say about it?

Surprisingly, it doesn't actually *dictate* a specific spin-up method--only that the pressure hull and shielding should be completed first, so that spin-up can occur as soon as possible to make interior construction easier. However, it does *mention* a spin-up method:

> If the shield is used as a reaction mass during spin-up of the torus it would counter-rotate at approximately
> 0.07 rpm; the relative velocity between the shield and the torus, would thus be about 100 m/s. The torus is prevented from scraping against the shield by a positive positioning device.

So: just use electric motors to drive wheels to react against the exterior radiation shield, which is designed to be far more massive than the habitation structure. Then the net angular momentum of the station remains zero, and controlling the spin rate to account for internal movement and additional of materials during construction is easy.

Comment: The thing I don’t understand about this design is how they intend to maintain the radiation shield in eclipse of the sun’s view from everyone at all times. It would seem that at some point along the combined orbits of earth and itself, combined with perturbations by the moon, there would be some part of the habitat opposit the shielding (along the inside of the ring) that  becomes exposed to the sun. This doesn’t relate to the OP question however, just a challenge to the whole concept. Seems the shield would be compromised without at least some means of adjustment.

Comment: @VogonPoet Just build it edge-on to the sun. Then you only need to worry about tidal perturbations, which are small for a body of this size, and can be countered with station-keeping thrusters.

Comment: It would have to have a very bizarre and unnatural orbit to maintain that orientation as the earth travels around the sun. As it orbits earth it will tend to remain in a single orbital plane, which would have to be exactly parallel to the earth own orbital plane to maintain the shield's eclipse. That puts it perpendicular to the earth's surface at all times, bobbing slightly above and below the equator. I suppose that could work... was that in the design paper?

Comment: @VogonPoet The station's orbital plane around the Earth does *not* have to be parallel to the orbital plane of the Earth around the sun. Indeed, it would not be as designed--the original Stanford Torus is intended to be built at the Lunar L5 point, so it would be in the Moon's orbital plane. The resulting angular deviation in the position of the sun throughout an orbit of the Earth is negligible--just align the plane of the station to the average position of the sun, and you're good.

Comment: The lunar orbit is inclined to the ecliptic plane by about 5.145 degrees so we’re both right.. A sliver of sunlight will peek around the shield twice per year. Following the lunar orbit makes logistical sense, reducing the tidal influences.

Comment: @VogonPoet If you align the rotation plane of the station parallel to the ecliptic then the Sun will always be eclipsed by the radiation shield, even at L5. Looks like a total deviation throughout the month of around 3.42 minutes of arc... which seems small enough to be covered by the shield.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this that I find interesting. First:

> once you build the mega-structure how do you make it start rotating?

There are many options for this including - but certainly not limited to - equatorial thrusters (in balanced sets of course), counter-rotating weights or paired torii, even balanced solar mirrors providing torque. Personally I like the idea of building two torii next to each other, spinning them up in opposite directions then separating them once they reach operational velocity. That way you get two spin-ups at once and twice the habitat space.

The more interesting part of the question though - at least from my perspective - is the second half:

> Also, given the structure is in space, is the energy required for rotation a one time expenditure? Or will friction come in to play and multiple periodic boosts would be required?

Even if you were building your toroid in one of the inter-galactic voids, friction will be a thing. The closer you are to a planet or star the higher the density of particles in the surrounding volume, and thus the higher your friction. We can mitigate this slightly by building very smooth outer hulls and so on, but you'll never eliminate the drag caused by rotating in an imperfect vaccuum.

It's not just the friction you need to balance against either. Every time you bring something onto the station, and every time you take something away, the rotational speed of your station changes a tiny bit. Lifting a mass from the 'surface' to your center of rotation will speed up your rotation, bringing mass down from the center to the surface will slow it down. You'll need some way to account for those variations when they are large enough... but as long as you're not moving *large* masses around you should be fine. You'll probably have more issues with balancing the spin when mass distribution changes.

And of course there's the issue of gyroscopic precession and tumbling. Anything that produces unbalanced thrust against the spinning station could produce unexpected forces. That's another argument for counter-rotating pairs, I reckon.

Comment: The two counter-rotating tori is a very interesting compromise, but the force required for each one is still 10^12 Newtons if we’re talking about a spec Stanford torus for 10,000 souls. Double that for your scenario. What non-magical motor exactly is providing this impulse?? And how is it fueled? Again, motor > than rockets, but still. We are talking about 20,000,000 short tons getting up to 2 rpm (in your scenario). Creative, but Structural limitations seem to say this won’t happen at the hub.

Comment: @VogonPoet The trick is that you don't apply rotational force at the hub, you do it at the rim. Still a lot of energy, sure, but a ring of motors between the two torii can apply small amounts of force continuously, pushing each torus in opposite directions to get the counter-rotation. The motors themselves would be stationary relative to some arbitrary inertial reference frame.

Comment: there might be a workable solution here using trams pulling the rings against each other, or some such. It still requires the construction of two megastructures, then how do you separate them?? (calculate that force!!)

Comment: @VogonPoet For separation I imagine decoupling the hubs of each torus then using ion thrusters or similar to have them drift apart and into their respective orbits. Force required then becomes a function of time: the more time you're happy to use, the less force you need. It's going to take a number of years to build the thing and get it spun up, I don't mind spending a few more years pushing them around. It would be slow enough to let us occupy the torus while it's being moved, so we have loads of time.

Comment: @VogonPoet Or you could just keep the pair together. Seems like that would be a more stable solution all 'round, doesn't it? Downside being that the hub becomes a much more interesting construction requiring some serious engineering to pull off.

Comment: Seems @LoganR.Kearsley was the only one who actually read the specs on the Stanford torus and it turns out only 5% of the mass is spinning. This brings two points of errata to our answers (mine included): The OP questions was already answered in the design, and there WILL be friction requiring energy to keep it spinning. However, having two tori of 1/2 the original scale in counter-rotation simplifies the major construction while greatly complicating the hub.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that any large scale station or habitat would have a thruster network anyway in order to maintain its orbital position. Depending on the orbital position of the Torus, such as at certain Lagrange points, station keeping thrusters would be required for orbital corrections and maintenance. You could use these thrusters to provide the initial spin for the station.

Answer (score 0):

I’m issuing a frame challenge to the seemingly practical idea that the torus needs to be started at all. Intuitively, we see the problem as two steps: Build torus, spin torus. This is where reality and common sense diverge. Let’s consider spinning a flywheel made of bolted/riveted parts that is 2.2 miles wide and has a mass of 10 million short tons. There is simply no technology that can give this thing a smooth and steady push up to 1 RPM, nor is it possible to keep it from tearing apart as you push it from a few points. You need to distribute the thrust over thousands of points, with a slow and steady thrust maintained for years.

So, after my own experience in the St. Louis Arch Nations Park, that construction led me to realize that the force of gravity which everyone saw as an obstacle was leveraged to bring the curves together in a very practical way. The same principle applies to your torus, which is simply an assembly of several arches under centrifugal force, when spinning.

The intuitive “static” construction brings many variables, and many opportunities for failure once it’s spun up. Reality has unintended consequences that won’t ever show up on paper. Definitely not for such a novel engineering feat as this. So the solutions is to keep the environment constant, never introducing the variables of spinning it up. How?

You begin building the torus at the hub by very simply spinning the hub components, with crane rigging on it that will be removed later. Spinning has no effect on your orientation in space unless you at at the axis of rotation, in fact it provides and orienting “downward” force to facilitate work. So workers will move outward along the spokes while the assembly is already spinning.

Construction is worked on each spoke simultaneously, having components given their initial matching spin, then delivered to the hub, and lowered down the spoke by the central crane system. During the difficult periods of construction, as the crews get further down the spokes, they can actually sit and take breaks. They can rest their tools on a platform (still tethered, obviously), and work in a much more comfortable environment.

As the construct gains mass, synchronizing work on each spoke becomes less important, because the components will be a smaller fraction of the whole mass. I imagine 5 meter sections of spoke tube will be mass produced, delivered to the hub, and lowered to the ends of their spokes to be simply bolted together.

When the spokes are complete, they form a crane system to build the ring. Connect each spoke end by a taught cable, and bring your ring components out to meet in the center. You’re not adding any mass that isn’t already designed into it, nor are you worried about why might fly off once you spin it. No new forces are introduced.

**Alternatively** - the spokes continue to serve as crane supports. Start with the center of each arc suspended by two spokes near the hub. “Lower” it toward the perimeter and add another segment. Lower, add, lower, add… until an arc is hanging between each pair of spokes, naturally pulling its curvature outward. Just connect them the the spoke ends.

I guess the short answer to the question is, spin every part individually during assembly and don’t worry about the whole dangerous and unnecessary spinning evolution. You will only need small thrusters to occasionally maintain spin.

Comment: The danger of spinning during construction is that any workers who fall off will then fly away from the station at possibly high velocity. You can't fall off a non-rotating station in progress.

Comment: The law of conservation of angular momentum means that your initial spin is going to be slowed by every bit of mass you send down the spokes. You'd have to keep adding more spin during the entire construction effort... and lose so many tools to centrifugal force.

Comment: Not true. The same energy is put into the rotation in either case, however the OP problem of using these massive thrusters all in a single spin-up is broken down into spinning every part as it is assembled. A cable connected to the hub will be pulled to the perimeter. A load on that cable (a crane) will also be pulled to the perimeter, using a small assist impulse to keep it aligned. The point is, parts are not deriving their momentum from the station mass but from a small initial (manageable) vehicle. Many small incremental thrusts vice one huge push. & Tools/people are tethered per usual.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan As stated, I am not arguing to remove the same tethers used in high rise construction and in space walks today. Basic safety practices & common sense should be part of the construction. & anstronauts absolutely CAN fall off a station flying at 18,000 mph in orbit (where did the idea of “stationary” come from?) Working in zero G is not as easy and convenient as you think it is. Having a sense of “down” will dramatically improve comfort and construction. Ask any astronaut!

Comment: Obviously, everything is in orbit. So "fall off" is clearly relative to *where all the life support systems are at*. I would assume that safety systems would be in place no matter how the station is constructed, but it doesn't change the fact that in one scenario, letting go of a tool means it just floats there until you grab it again, and in the other, it becomes a possibly deadly projectile to everyone who is "below" you.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan I believe astronauts have a very different experience with floating tools. The smallest bump or nudge sends it beyond your short 25” arm’s reach in seconds. An ancient invention called a “net” on the other hand, makes dropped tools easily recoverable. Nets need a directional force to work. Mental excercise: You’re in 0G and loose grip of a wrench. Try to grab it with space suit gloves, without just pushing it away. Not an easy task, it’s not just sitting still waiting for you. In a net, it’s just sitting there waiting for you, even if you take a nap.